# Controlling a 5m WS2812 LED Strip. Which power supply?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, power-supply, led, breadboard

I read the following tutorial: http://popoklopsi.github.io/RaspberryPi-LedStrip/#!/ws2812

In the tutorial 1m of WS2812 led strip is used and it is stated, that its power supply needs a maximum of 3,6A.
Now I want to do this with a 5m led strip, which has 30leds/m, which is a total of 150 leds. In the tutorial it is explained, that 1 led needs a maximum of 60mA. So I would have to buy a power supply with 5V and 9A. Is there anything like this, because I didn't find one or is this incorrect ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5V/10A enclosed switched-mode power supplies are relatively inexpensive and plentiful. At the time of writing you can buy them for around £10-£20 from:

- [DigiKey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/power-supplies-external-internal-off-board/ac-dc-converters/590377?FV=1180004f%2C17d4003e%2Cfff40009%2Cfff80229&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=5v+10a+supply)
- [RS Components](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/power-supplies-transformers/power-supplies-psus/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/?searchTerm=5v+10a+supply#esid=4294957161&sort-by=P_breakPrice1&sort-order=asc)
- [Farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=44&storeId=10151&categoryId=700000004428&sort=P_PRICE&eq=N%3D213135%2B111782152%2B111782174%2B111827736%2B2031%26amp%3BNs%3DP_STORE_MARKETING_RANK_FARNELL_UK%257c0%257c%257cP_MAN_PART_NUM%257c0%26amp%3BNtpc%3D1%26amp%3BNtpr%3D1&showResults=true&aa=true&pf=111782152,111782174,111827736&vw=)
- [Ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Woo-DC-5V-10A-Regulated-Switching-Power-Supply-Transformer-/400931249615?hash=item5d595d5dcf:g:QzQAAOxy3zNSnr4a)
- [AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/af/5v-10a-power-supply.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.2.4RlqaJ&site=glo&SearchText=5v+10a&g=y&CatId=14191104&initiative_id=SB_20160730040203&isAffiliate=y&shipCountry=uk&isrefine=y)
- [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/AC220V-Driver-Switching-Power-Supply/dp/B008DFBSTQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1469880221&sr=8-1&keywords=5v+10a+power+supply)
- [Mouser](http://www.mouser.co.uk/Power/Power-Supplies/Switching-Power-Supplies/_/N-axgkh?P=1yxt7f4Z1yxt5vkZ1yxt7afZ1yxt6edZ1yxt7a5Z1yxt74vZ1yxt6taZ1yxt74nZ1yxt7euZ1yxt794Z1yxt6tpZ1yxt79wZ1yxt6xmZ1yxt6w4Z1yzce8g&Keyword=switching+power&Ns=Pricing%7c0&FS=True)
- [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/658)

Whatever you finish up using, I'd recommend taking a look through the [Powering Neopixels](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/power) section of the [Adafruit NeoPixel Überguide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/overview). It has some useful suggestions for working with longer runs of WS2812s.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble finding a power supply that can deliver enough current you could simply use an old computer's power supply, it should have more than enough amps on the 5V rail and they are technically free!